# Saturation dissolved oxygen level at pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, solubility, gas-laws

The saturation level of dissolved oxygen in contact with a moist atmosphere is

$$c = 0.21(p_\mathrm{atm} - p_\mathrm{vap}) K_\mathrm{H} M$$

where the $p_\mathrm{atm}$ and $p_\mathrm{vap}$ are the atmospheric and vapour pressures, respectively; $K_\mathrm{H}$ is the Henry's law constant, and $M$ is the molar mass.

If I take this volume of water away from the atmospheric interface, and reduce the pressure, does the saturation level equation stay the same as above, except swapping out $p_\mathrm{atm}$ for $p_\mathrm{local}$?

Comment: Yes, if p-local is made up of air and water vapor and the water vapor partial pressure at local is included.  But this will be when the system re-equilibrates.